# Custom non-linear matrix multiplication in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have to matrices `U` and `W`:

```py
U = np.arange(6*2).reshape((6,2))
W = np.arange(5*2).reshape((5,2))
```

For a standard linear multiplication, I could do:

```py
U @ W.T
```

```
array([[  1,   3,   5,   7,   9],
       [  3,  13,  23,  33,  43],
       [  5,  23,  41,  59,  77],
       [  7,  33,  59,  85, 111],
       [  9,  43,  77, 111, 145],
       [ 11,  53,  95, 137, 179]])
```

But I could also (technically) define a linear multiplication function, do this column-wise and sum in a for-loop:

```py
def mult(U, W, i):
  return U[:, [i]] @ W.T[[i],:]

sum([mult(U, W, i) for i in range(2)]) #1
```

```
array([[  1,   3,   5,   7,   9],
       [  3,  13,  23,  33,  43],
       [  5,  23,  41,  59,  77],
       [  7,  33,  59,  85, 111],
       [  9,  43,  77, 111, 145],
       [ 11,  53,  95, 137, 179]])
```

Now suppose `mult()` isn't linear anymore, it is non-linear, custom, for example:

```py
def mult(U, W, i):
  return (U[:, [i]] @ W.T[[i],:]) * np.cos(U[:, [i]] @ W.T[[i],:])

sum([mult(U, W, i) for i in range(2)]) #2
```

You can verify this isn't identical to `(U @ W.T) * np.cos(U @ W.T)`. But I wonder is there a more compact way of writing `#2`, just as there is a more compact way of writing `#1` if `mult()` is linear. Efficiency would be nice but I'm not dealing with huge matrices.

Comment: Your 2d @ can be written as: `(U[:,None,:]*W[None,:,:]).sum(axis=2)`.  Try the same thing with the other calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@`, like `np.dot` is a matrix multiplication, involving what we often call a sum-of-products.  This is a basic linear algebra operation, and `np.matmul` uses highly efficient compiled libraries to do this (where possible).

Your `sum([mult(...))` is doing that - take the row/column products and summing them.  The compiled code probably uses more efficient methods that work well in iterative `c` or `Fortran`.

Your `mult` function could use broadcasted element-wise multiplication.  For one `i`:

```
In [43]: i=1;U[:, [i]] @ W.T[[i],:]     # (6,1) @ (1,5) => (6,5)
Out[43]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9],
       [ 3,  9, 15, 21, 27],
       [ 5, 15, 25, 35, 45],
       [ 7, 21, 35, 49, 63],
       [ 9, 27, 45, 63, 81],
       [11, 33, 55, 77, 99]])

In [44]: i=1;U[:, [i]] * W.T[[i],:]
Out[44]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9],
       [ 3,  9, 15, 21, 27],
       [ 5, 15, 25, 35, 45],
       [ 7, 21, 35, 49, 63],
       [ 9, 27, 45, 63, 81],
       [11, 33, 55, 77, 99]])
```

And without the list comprehension this can be written as:

```
In [46]: (U[:,None,:]*W[None,:,:]).shape
Out[46]: (6, 5, 2)

In [47]: (U[:,None,:]*W[None,:,:]).sum(axis=2)
Out[47]: 
array([[  1,   3,   5,   7,   9],
       [  3,  13,  23,  33,  43],
       [  5,  23,  41,  59,  77],
       [  7,  33,  59,  85, 111],
       [  9,  43,  77, 111, 145],
       [ 11,  53,  95, 137, 179]])
```

As for your version with `np.cos:

```
In [48]: def mult(U, W, i):
    ...:   return (U[:, [i]] @ W.T[[i],:]) * np.cos(U[:, [i]] @ W.T[[i],:])
    ...: sum([mult(U, W, i) for i in range(2)]) #2
Out[48]: 
array([[ 5.40302306e-01, -2.96997749e+00,  1.41831093e+00,
         5.27731578e+00, -8.20017236e+00],
       [-2.96997749e+00, -1.08147468e+01, -1.25593190e+01,
        -1.37606696e+00, -2.32102995e+01],
       [ 1.41831093e+00, -1.25593190e+01,  9.45751861e+00,
        -2.14489310e+01,  5.03346370e+01],
       [ 5.27731578e+00, -1.37606696e+00, -2.14489310e+01,
         1.01223418e+01,  3.13845563e+01],
       [-8.20017236e+00, -2.32102995e+01,  5.03346370e+01,
         3.13845563e+01,  8.79904273e+01],
       [ 4.86826779e-02,  7.72350858e+00, -2.54605509e+01,
        -5.95298563e+01, -4.88871235e+00]])
```

I can use the same outer/sum format:

```
In [49]: (U[:,None,:]*W[None,:,:]*np.cos(U[:,None,:]*W[None,:,:])).sum(axis=2)
Out[49]: 
array([[ 5.40302306e-01, -2.96997749e+00,  1.41831093e+00,
         5.27731578e+00, -8.20017236e+00],
       [-2.96997749e+00, -1.08147468e+01, -1.25593190e+01,
        -1.37606696e+00, -2.32102995e+01],
       [ 1.41831093e+00, -1.25593190e+01,  9.45751861e+00,
        -2.14489310e+01,  5.03346370e+01],
       [ 5.27731578e+00, -1.37606696e+00, -2.14489310e+01,
         1.01223418e+01,  3.13845563e+01],
       [-8.20017236e+00, -2.32102995e+01,  5.03346370e+01,
         3.13845563e+01,  8.79904273e+01],
       [ 4.86826779e-02,  7.72350858e+00, -2.54605509e+01,
        -5.95298563e+01, -4.88871235e+00]])
```

And since the outer product is used twice, we can use a temporary variable:

```
In [51]: temp=U[:,None,:]*W[None,:,:]; 
         (temp*np.cos(temp)).sum(axis=2)
Out[51]: 
array([[ 5.40302306e-01, -2.96997749e+00,  1.41831093e+00,
         5.27731578e+00, -8.20017236e+00],
       [-2.96997749e+00, -1.08147468e+01, -1.25593190e+01,
        -1.37606696e+00, -2.32102995e+01],
       [ 1.41831093e+00, -1.25593190e+01,  9.45751861e+00,
        -2.14489310e+01,  5.03346370e+01],
       [ 5.27731578e+00, -1.37606696e+00, -2.14489310e+01,
         1.01223418e+01,  3.13845563e+01],
       [-8.20017236e+00, -2.32102995e+01,  5.03346370e+01,
         3.13845563e+01,  8.79904273e+01],
       [ 4.86826779e-02,  7.72350858e+00, -2.54605509e+01,
        -5.95298563e+01, -4.88871235e+00]])
```

The fact that you can't simply interchange the multiplication and sum steps is a matter of basic algebra.

To get

```
a1*b1 + a2*b2
```

from

```
(a1+a2)*(b1+b2) => a1*b1 + a1*b2 + a2*b1 + a2*b2
```

the `a1*b2 + a2*b1` terms have to sum to zero, as with the magnitude of a complex number:

```
In [53]: (1+4j)*(1-4j)
Out[53]: (17+0j)    # (1+16)
```

The sum of products cannot, in general be converted to a product of sums.